# How to group partially matching rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe of product variants with their descriptions, colorIDs and quantity sold, how do I group these variants into the main product and add up the quantities sold for each? You can see the variants share some of the descriptive text but the colors and sizes don't match.

Input data (extract):

| Description | ColorID | Quantity Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rollerball pen (Blue) | 3 | 100 |
| Packing Box 305x215x150mm | 0 | 50 |
| Coffee Mug (White) | 1 | 45 |
| Rollerball pen (Black) | 2 | 220 |
| Packing Box 215x215x100mm | 0 | 85 |
| Micro Correct Fluid 10ml | 0 | 80 |
| Coffee Mug (Black) | 2 | 40 |

Expected Result:

| Description | Quantity Sold |
| --- | --- |
| Rollerball pen | 320 |
| Packing Box | 135 |
| Coffee Mug | 85 |
| Micro Correct Fluid 10ml | 80 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `assign()`,`rsplit()` and `groupby()`:

```
out=(df.assign(Description=df['Description'].str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0])
        .groupby('Description',as_index=False,sort=False)['Quantity Sold'].sum())
```

output of `out`:

```
    Description         Quantity Sold
0   Rollerball pen          320
1   Packing Box             135
2   Coffee Mug              85
3   Micro Correct Fluid     80
```